# R: Panel Data Clustered Standard Errors

Tags: r, panel-data, clustered-standard-errors

I have a panel regression and like to proof the robustness of my model. I estimated a fixed effects model with double clustered SEs.

I estimated:

1. an OLS - pooled model
2. Fixed effects model Index: Group & time with robust SEs
3. Fixed effect model Group-fixed
4. Fixed effect model Time-fixed

I use `plm` for the regressions. Now, when i want to simply cluster my SEs for mode #2 and model #3 it yields me the same SEs. Even though i leave out the Cluster =  command (in line 50).

How is that possible?

Further I tried to use `vcovCL()` for the clustering (in line 57 & 64) but I get an error:

```
 Error in UseMethod("estfun") : 
  no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "c('plm', 'panelmodel')"
```

````
library(plm)
library(lmtest)
library(stargazer)
library(sandwich)
library(etable)
library(pacman)
library(fixest)
library(multiwayvcov)
library(foreign)
library(estimatr)

#cleaning 
extra <- pdata.frame(New_R_done, index=c("ISIN", "Date"))
str(extra)
extra <- extra %>% na.omit()
View(extra)

#Return 
extra$Returns <- ifelse(extra$Returns=="n.a", 0, extra$Returns)
#Flows
extra$Flows <- ifelse(extra$Flows=="n.a", 0, extra$Flows)
#TNA
extra$TNA <- ifelse(extra$TNA=="n.a", 0, extra$TNA)
#Age
extra$Age <- ifelse(extra$Age=="n.a", 0, extra$Age)

#adjust units of TNA and Flows has to be done to run regressions in plm
#extra <- extra %>%   
#mutate(TNA = TNA / 1000000, Flows = Flows / 1000000) #1mio and 1mio 

#variable creation for model
Y200 <- cbind(extra$Flows)
X200 <- cbind(extra$Dummy, lag(extra$Returns), lag(extra$TNA), extra$Age) 

# descriptive statistics 
summary(Y200)
summary(X200)

#pooled OLS no fixed effects no clustered standard erros  
pooled_extra <- plm(Flows ~ Dummy + lag(Returns) + lag(TNA) + Age, data = extra, model = "pooling")
summary(pooled_extra)
#robust std errors not clustered 
lm_robust(Flows ~ Dummy + lag(Returns) + lag(TNA) + Age, data = extra)
vis1 <- plm(Flows ~ Dummy + lag(Returns) + lag(TNA) + Age, data = extra, model = "pooling")

#fixed effect model time and fund 
fixed_extra_fd <- plm(Flows ~ Dummy + lag(Returns) + lag(TNA) + Age, data = extra, model='within', index=c('ISIN', 'Date'))
summary(fixed_extra_fd)
#robust std errors
coeftest(fixed_extra_fd, vcov=vcovHC(fixed_extra_fd,type="HC0"))
vis2 <- coeftest(fixed_extra_fd, vcov=vcovHC(fixed_extra_fd,type="HC0"))

#FUND fixed effect 
fixed_extra_f <- plm(Flows ~ Dummy + lag(Returns) + lag(TNA) + Age, data = extra, model='within', index=c('ISIN'))
summary(fixed_extra_f)
#cluster std errors by FUND 
coeftest(fixed_extra_d, vcov=vcovHC(fixed_extra_d,type="HC0", cluster = "group"))
vis3 <- coeftest(fixed_extra_f, vcov=vcovHC(fixed_extra_f,type="HC0", cluster = "group"))

#TIME fixed effect
fixed_extra_d <- plm(Flows ~ Dummy + lag(Returns) + lag(TNA) + Age, data = extra, model='within', index=c('Date'))
summary(fixed_extra_d)
#clsuter std errors by DATE
coeftest(fixed_extra_d, vcov=vcovHC(fixed_extra_d,type="HC0", cluster = "time"))
vis4 <- coeftest(fixed_extra_d, vcov=vcovHC(fixed_extra_d,type="HC0", cluster = "time"))

#visualize
stargazer(vis1, vis2, vis3, vis4, type = "text")
```
````

Comment: For `plm::vcovHC`, `cluster = "group"` is the default, so explicitly specifying it will not change the output. See `?plm::vcovHC` for what is the default.

Comment: Ran into the same problem. I think this is a bug in the `sandwich` package - it should be able to use `plm` objects - I'll contact the package authors. If you update your tags or title to mention plm, they might pick this up